# display alternate image in an array by checking existing another array whether the element is present or not in angular2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have two arrays like this

```
arr1[]= [{name:"aaa",id:"23"},{name:"aaa",id:"24"},{name:"aaa",id:"25"},{name:"aaa",id:"26"}];
arr2[]=[{name:"aaa",id:"23"},{name:"aaa",id:"24"},{name:"aaa",id:"25"}];
```

I want to display **a.jpg** for elements of matched between arrays
and **b.jpg** images for unmatched elements. How do I proceed this in angular2?

```js
 for(var i=0; i< this.ticketlists.length; i++ )
            {
              for(var j=0; j<this.favlist.length; j++)
              {
                if(this.ticketlists[i].id == this.favlist[j].id)
                {
                  this.ticketlists[i].starimgsass = "assets/images/star_icon.png";
                  console.log("matched id",this.ticketlists[i].id);
                }
                else
                {
                  this.ticketlists[i].starimgsass = "assets/images/star_icon1.png";
                  console.log("unmached id",this.ticketlists[i].id);
                }
              }
            }
```

```html
<ul class="listboxtickets">
    <li class="selectlistticket" *ngFor="let tick of ticketlists">
      <div class="atickid"> {{tick.id}}  </div>
      <div class="atickname"> {{tick.summary.substring(0,20)}} </div>
      <div class="atickstat"> <img class="staraimg" [src]="tick.starimgsass" (click)="changeassigntofav(tick.id)"/> </div>
      <div class="namelinet"> <img src="assets/images/text_bottomline.png"/> </div>
    </li>
```

this is not work well

Comment: Can you describe your question better with a good example? In your case you have match: `0`, `1` and `3`, so you have to list **a.jpg** three times and **b.jpg** 2 time or what ?

Comment: I'm very close enough to my answer. I want to compare two different sized arrays

Comment: actually i have two arrays which is got from http service response, that array contains different elements. I want to display image depends on matching their unique elements,if it matches then shows a.jpg image,if not shows b.jpg image.I hope u can understand this problem. And i cannot use let or  *ngfor,bcoz i'm using latest beta version

Comment: I updated my question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for(var i=0; i< this.ticketlists.length; i++ )
            {
              for(var j=0; j<this.favlist.length; j++)
              {
                if(this.ticketlists[i].id == this.favlist[j].req_id)
                {
                  this.ticketlists[i].starimgsass = "assets/images/star_icon1.png";
                  console.log("matched id",this.ticketlists[i].id);
                }
              }
            }
            // this.ticketlists = [];
            for(var i=0; i< this.ticketlists.length; i++ )
            {
              if(this.ticketlists[i].starimgsass == null)
              {
                this.ticketlists[i].starimgsass = "assets/images/star_icon.png";
              }
            }
```

This works ultimately fine

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <img [attr.src]="source(i)" *ngFor="let x of arr1; let i = index;">
  `,
})
export class App {
  arr1= [0,1,2,3,4];
  arr2=[0,1,3];

  source(i) {
    const inBoth = this.arr1.some(a => i === a) && this.arr2.some(a => i === a);
    return inBoth ? 'a.jpg' : 'b.jpg'
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fm2nLhK4Or7a26CIcjsA?p=info)